# Selenium in a for loop reuses first value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to use selenium to check multiple accounts on a website.

I have a url and then a list with the data

```
url = 'website.com' 
data = [(username1, password1), (username2, password2), (username3, password3)]
```

And then I am using a for loop to get the data:

```
for username, password: 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
    username.send_keys(username)
    password.send_keys(password)
    # etc
```

The problem is that selenium always uses the first value pair of the list; hence I know the code works but I only get the right data for the first user.

Do I need to reset the webdriver ro something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful, dont use same variable name.

Loop over data list of tuples

But this will open N browsers, you can reuse same browser moving driver = webdriver.Chrome() out of the loop

```
data = [(username1, password1), (username2, password2), (username3, password3)]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for u, p in data: 
    
    driver.get(url)
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
    username.send_keys(u)
    password.send_keys(p)
```

Comment: It's a best practice to use a new driver/browser for each test. That ensures that each test is run as clean as possible.